# Select a number of top groups from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Is there an efficient way to grab some number of top groups from a data frame in R?
For example:

```
exampleDf <- data.frame(
  subchar = c("facebook", "twitter", "snapchat", "male", "female", "18", "20"),
  superchar = c("social media", "social media", "social media", "gender", "gender", "age", "age"),
  cweight = c(.2, .4, .4, .7, .3, .8, .6),
  groupWeight = c(10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 70, 70)
)
```

So with dplyr I can group them and sort by group weight with:

```
sortedDf <- exampleDf %>%
  group_by(superchar) %>%
  arrange(desc(groupWeight))
```

But is there anyway to select the 'top' groups, like age and gender in this case? Kind of like the slice() dplyr function, but for the whole group rather than rows within the group.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'top groups'?

Comment: This seems like a weird example because `groupWeight` is unique within groups, but it's not a group id, so the groups don't really matter.  In a case like this, I'd do `exampleDf %>% filter(groupWeight %in% sort(unique(groupWeight), decreasing = TRUE)[1:2])`. The more interesting case is if `groupWeight` varies within the group, but then you need to specify what summary function of `groupWeight` to use (mean, median, max, etc.). And probably the best way is to `exampleDf %>% group_by %>% summarize %>% top_n %>% left_join(exampleDf)` back to the original data.

Comment: @heds1 Sorry should have clarified that, in this case it would be the groups with highest groupWeight. So the rank here would be Age first, then gender, and social media the lowest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr` has a `group_indices` function that can be used to assign a consecutive group number. Then `filter` by that new number. In the example below, I will filter/keep the 2 first groups.

```
library(dplyr)

Top <- 2

sortedDf <- exampleDf %>%
  group_by(superchar) %>%
  arrange(desc(groupWeight)) %>%
  mutate(new_id = group_indices()) %>%
  filter(new_id <= Top) %>%
  select(-new_id)

sortedDf
## A tibble: 4 x 4
## Groups:   superchar [2]
#  subchar superchar cweight groupWeight
#  <fct>   <fct>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 18      age           0.8          70
#2 20      age           0.6          70
#3 male    gender        0.7          20
#4 female  gender        0.3          20
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two other approaches using `dplyr` :

We calculate `sum` of `groupWeight` for each `superchar` select top 2 records and do a `left_join` with the original dataframe to select all the rows.

```
n <- 2
library(dplyr)

exampleDf %>%
  group_by(superchar) %>%
  summarise(sum_gr = sum(groupWeight)) %>%
  top_n(n, sum_gr) %>%
  left_join(exampleDf)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  superchar sum_gr subchar cweight groupWeight
#  <fct>      <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 age          140 18          0.8          70
#2 age          140 20          0.6          70
#3 gender        40 male        0.7          20
#4 gender        40 female      0.3          20
```

---

Another approach is to `sum` `groupWeight` by `superchar` and use `dense_rank` to select top groups.

```
exampleDf %>%
  group_by(superchar) %>%
  mutate(sum_gr = sum(groupWeight)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(dense_rank(-sum_gr) <= n)
```

---

The first approach can be written in base R as :

```
temp <- aggregate(groupWeight~superchar, exampleDf, sum)
temp <- temp[order(temp$groupWeight, decreasing = TRUE), ][1:n, ]
merge(temp, exampleDf, all.x = TRUE, by = 'superchar')
```